# How to make UIWindow transparent

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I need to see the `HomeScreen` from the `UIWindow` by making the `UIWindow` background as transparent. How to achieve this ?

I have tried with `[UIColor ClearColor];` But its displaying BlackColor only.

Comment: Can you explain why do you really need this ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not possible to see the homescreen inside your app. Apple did this to save power (who needs to render the homescreen while he's using an app) and to prevent devs from irritating users by making them think they are on their homescreen.

Answer (score 1):

This is not good to do but its necessary then i think you use like below might be userful to you

```
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:55.0f green:55.0f blue:55.0 alpha:0.05];
```